# Change locked cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a VBA code to get sums but it does not work when cells are locked.

I want that no one can change the value of the specific cell manually but the VBA code can change the value.

My code is

```
Sub Get_Sum()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("B5000").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("D" & LastRow + 1) = "Total Amount"
    Range("E" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUM(E4:E" & LastRow & ")"
    Range("F" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUM(F4:F" & LastRow & ")"
    Range("G" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUM(G4:G" & LastRow & ")"
End Sub
```

where cells E (column E) are locked with a password.

Comment: Unlock the sheet before performing your code and then lock it afterwards. http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/VBA/7134.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can do it this way:

```
Sub Get_Sum()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Sheets("Sheetname").Unprotect Password:= "password"
    LastRow = Range("B5000").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("D" & LastRow + 1) = "Total Amount"
    Range("E" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUM(E4:E" & LastRow & ")"
    Range("F" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUM(F4:F" & LastRow & ")"
    Range("G" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUM(G4:G" & LastRow & ")"
    Sheets("Sheetname").Protect Password:= "password"
End Sub
```